The number of passwords that can be made from 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 if 0 appears once
How many 6-digit passwords are there, if the passwords can be made out of 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4, for each password the number 0 can only appear once?
(This is what I've been thinking):

It's possible to have $110111$, $123403$, or $444440$, but it can't be $023420$ (because it has 2 zeroes in it)

My attempt:
Using filling slots, I got $$5\times 4\times 4\times 4\times 4 \times 4 = 5120$$
However, the choices are:
A) $360$
B) $720$
C) $1440$
D) $2880$
E) $5760$
My answer isn't either of them. So what would it be? Assuming there is lacking information or hidden assumptions that I do not know, is it still possible to answer this problem?
Thank you in advance!

Note that while your answer is wrong, so are all of the possible answers you list. Are you sure you typed the question correctly?

I was able to obtain one of the given answers by assuming that all of the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ are used at least once and $0$ is used exactly once.  However, that interpretation is not remotely clear from the wording of the question.

@5xum I believe I have translated the question correctly. It was in another language.

Given the way the question is written, I would interpret the question the way that 5xum did.  However, given the list of possible answers, it seems the intended question was:

How many six-digit passwords using all of the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ are there in which the digit $0$ appears exactly once?

Under that (non-obvious) interpretation, exactly one of the digits $1, 2, 3, 4$ must appear twice.  There are four ways to select that number, $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to select two positions for that number, and $4!$ ways to arrange the remaining four digits ($0$ and the three digits among $1, 2, 3, 4$ that have not yet been used) in the remaining four positions.  That yields
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{6}{2}4! = 1440$$

You calculated the number of passwords where the first digit is any of $0,1,2,3,4$ and it is followed by 5 other digits, all being one of $1,2,3,4$.
The valid password $101111$ does not appear in your counting.
Hint: Try to count the number of passwords with exactly $0$ repetitions of $0$ and the number of passwords with exactly $1$ repetition of $0$ separately.

Note that as noted by @N.F.Taussig in the comments, it appears there is a hidden assumption in your question, and that is that all of the numbers must appear at least once in the list. With this assumption, one of the choices is correct. Without it, the number of passwords would be $4^6$ (number of passwords without $0$) plus $6\cdot 4^5$ (number of passwords with exactly one $0$) which adds up to $10240$

Your interpretation is the natural one.  However, the only way I was able to obtain one of the stated answers is to assume that all of the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4$ appear in the password and that $0$ is used exactly once.  If that was the intended interpretation of the question, it is not remotely clear from the wording.

@N.F.Taussig Nice insight, I added it to my answer.

I believe your $6\cdot 4^4$ should be $6\cdot 4^5$.

@N.F.Taussig Thanks for pointing that out. Cold you elaborate more please as I'm still having difficulty to understand your thought. Is it $5^6-5*4^5$?

@5xum Hi, thanks for the answer, I'd love to hear which way to make one of the choices correct?
